# Codeigniter set_flashdata in not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with codeigniter flashdata. Whenever i visit the page it is constantly showing the flashdata message.

Contoller :

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this
    ->Station_model>check_allowall($id , $station){

     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang("station_added"));
     redirect('Station');
}

else {
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', lang('station_required'));  
$this->data['page_title'] = lang('station_move');
$this->page_construct('Station/add', $this->data);  

}
```

View:

```
<?php 
if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?></strong>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: You set session data, it is showed. What do you expect?

Comment: Check might be somewhere redirection is there

Comment: Is there any message in `lang('station_required')`? Set message by custom. For e.g. `$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Test message'));`

Comment: Yeah but it is showing every time i visit the page. @u_mulder

Comment: Obviously you set it __every time__ in a controller.

Comment: `$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', lang('station_required'));`  Set this  message only when you want to show.

Comment: @u_mulder can you please help me out how can i set it for msg only

Comment: Show us your controller code.

Comment: `if ( $this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->Station_model    
          ->check_allowall($id , $station)  ){
         $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang("station_added"));
         redirect('Station');
    } 
    else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', lang('station_required'));  
    $this->data['page_title'] = lang('station_move');
    $this->page_construct('Station/add', $this->data);  

    }`

Comment: Put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect your page if there is no station.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->Station_model>check_allowall($id , $station)
{

     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang("station_added"));
     redirect('Station');
}

else 
{
     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', lang('station_required')); 
     redirect('Station'); 
}

$this->data['page_title'] = lang('station_move');
$this->page_construct('Station/add', $this->data);
```

In your station view page:

```
<?php 
if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?></strong>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```